# replace javascript regexp matched group with a dollar sign

Tags: javascript, regex

This one should be pretty simple :

Let's take the string : `str="1.99 or 4.89"`

I want to add a dollar sign in front of the amounts.

I tried :

```
str.replace(/(\d\.\d\d)/g,"$$1"));
```

it gives me : "$1 or $1"...

So I'm stuck with doing :

```
str.replace(/(\d\.\d\d)/g,"$ $1").replace(/\$ /g,'$')
```

It works but I'm sure there's a better way! I've tried escaping both $ signs, and a few other things...
Looking forward to your answers :)

Comment: `$1` means "the first matched characters". [To escape `$`, try `$$`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
"1.99 or 4.89".replace(/(\d\.\d\d)/g, "$$$1")
// => "$1.99 or $4.89"
```

Since `$` is special in replacement string, it must be escaped into `$$` for a literal `$`. It is not escaped using the `\` character, which is a general string escape mechanism, and processed before the string reaches `replace` (i.e. if you say `"\$"`, it becomes `"$"` before being passed as an argument, so `replace` never sees the escaping).